# Definite Improper Integral Endpoint Issue

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I've been working on how to evaluate:

$$\int_{1/\sqrt{3}}^\infty \left(\frac{5x \, dx}{4+9x^4} \right)$$

So far I've been able to reach this point:

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \left[\frac{5}{12}\arctan\left(\frac{3x^2}{2}\right)\right]$$

And along the way in my evaluation, I (according to my class notes,) have made changes to the endpoints as I ended up using substitution, in a table like this:

```
x         | u = 3x^2
--------------------
t         | 3t^2
--------------------
1/sqrt(3) | 1
```

But when I evaluate the "new" endpoints (`3t^2` and `1`), I end up with something like this:

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \left[\frac{5}{12}\arctan\left(\frac{3(3t^2)^2}{2}\right) \right] = \frac{5\pi}{24} $$

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \left[\frac{5}{12}\arctan\left(\frac{3(1)^2}{2}\right) \right] \approx 0.4095 $$

Which gives me this *approximate* final result:

$$\frac{5\pi}{24} - 0.4095 \approx 0.245$$

But according to the problem's answer, it appears that I need to be getting:

$$ \approx 0.461 $$

I think I've narrowed down the issue to this line:

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \left[\frac{5}{12}\arctan\left(\frac{3(1)^2}{2}\right) \right] \approx 0.4095 $$

But I'm not sure if the issue has to do with the endpoint changes I've made along the way in my problem, or if there is an extra property that goes along with that sort of `arctan()` evaluation.

Is there something obvious that I am missing at this point in my process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that you made the $u$-substitution $u=3x^2/2$ so that $du=3x~dx$. You'll need to fix your endpoints accordingly.

More importantly, keep this in mind:

> When you make a $u$-substitution, **either** substitute the modified endpoints (in terms of $u$), **or** convert back to $x$ and use the original endpoints (in terms of $x$); **don't do both**.

That is, you may evaluate either:
$$
\lim_{t\to \infty} \left[\frac{5}{12}\arctan \left(u \right) \right]_{u=1/2}^{3t^2/2} 
$$
or you may evaluate:
$$
\lim_{t\to \infty} \left[\frac{5}{12}\arctan \left(\frac{3x^2}{2} \right) \right]_{x=1/\sqrt{3}}^{t} 
$$

Answer (score 3):

You have made a substitution equivalent to $3x^2=2t$. This makes the lower limit $t=1/2$. When I calculate with that, I get an answer that is very close to the "official" one. The exact answer is
$$\frac{5}{12}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)  \right).$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; I can't believe I was using `3/2` when I should have used `1/2` with the substitution being used!  I guess I was mixing up the `x` variable with the whole `u/a` format of the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{a^2 + u^2}$ ...

Comment: You are welcome. Like typos, little glitches like this are inevitable, and have no significance. When grading, I usually give full marks for a clear solution with this kind of minor slip. Machines are unfortunately stupid about this.